# Ordenar Strings en array de menor a mayor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ordenar

Hola como están? Tengo que resolver un ejercicio y hace un día que lo estoy intentando pero no puedo llegar a resolverlo del todo.

La función recibe una matriz de strings. Ordena la matriz en orden creciente de longitudes de cadena. Ej: Recibe:

```
["vaso", "tierra", "habilidad", "exterminación", "dar", "de"]
```

Devuelve:

```
["de", "dar", "vaso", "tierra", "habilidad", "exterminación"].
```

Mi ultima solución es esta, en la cual convierto el `array` de strings a un `array` con sus `length`, luego dentro de ese array de `length` hago un `reduce` para obtener el mínimo, y luego uso ese mínimo para compararlo con el `length` de los elementos del `array` que vino por argumento, y pushear ese elemento a un `array` que va a contener el resultado. Finalmente con `.splice` elimino ese mínimo del `array` de los `length`.

El problema es que ahí el código finaliza y no se ejecuta de nuevo. Yo necesito volver a sacar el mínimo de nuevo del `array` ese de `length` y repetir todo hasta pushear todo ordenado...

Lo único que me retorna es ["de"]

```
function sortArray(arr) {
 

  let resultado = []; 
  arrayNumeros = arr.map(function (elemento) {
    return elemento.length;
  }); 

  let min = arrayNumeros.reduce(function (ac, el) {
    return Math.min(ac, el);
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (min === arr[i].length) {
      resultado.push(arr[i]);
    } 
    for (let j = 0; j < arrayNumeros.length; j++) {
      if (min === arrayNumeros[j]) {
        arrayNumeros.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  } 

  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Déjanos saber si te funcionó la respuesta haciendo click en el upvote y marcándola como aceptada con el check, ambos botones están al lado izquierdo en la respuesta. Si no te funcionó, te animo a dejar comentarios para saber si te podemos ayudar de otra manera.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método `sort()`, el cual, según la documentación en [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), *ordena los elementos de una matriz y devuelve la referencia a la misma matriz, ahora ordenada.*

Esto quiere decir que ordena los elementos en el mismo `array` y no se generan copias u otros `array`.

Puedes pasarle dos parámetros en una función anónima para hacer la comparación.

```js
//Obtener el array
let array = ["vaso", "tierra", "habilidad", "exterminación", "dar", "de"];
//Pasar como parámetros de comparación a y b
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  //Los queremos ordenados del mas corto al mas largo, por lo tanto usamos...
  return a.length - b.length
  //En caso contrario, usariamos return b.length - a.length
});
//Mostrar el resultado en pantalla...
document.write(array);
//o en consola
console.log(array);
```